# How to apply calculation on Springs @Value properties?

Tags: java, spring

```
application.properties:
//timeout in ms
timeout = 20000;

@Value("${timeout} / 1000")
private int timeoutInSeconds;
```

Is it possible to apply some calculations directly on a `@Value` attribute?
At least my example does not work this way...

Comment: you could use a `@PostConstruct` to apply some operation after initialization or you could use `#{${timeout}/1000}`

Answer (score 11):

To answer my own question:

`@Value("#{${timeout} / 1000}")`